# how to transfer value to widgets in Main window from another class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I setup a Main window with below codes :

```
import Main_BookSpace

class MainWindowClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QAction):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindowClass, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # SQL Database relate
        self.database = Main_database.DataBaseRelate()

        # init space booking sheet
        self.space_booking_class = Main_BookSpace.BookingSpaceClass(self.tableWidget, self.database)
        self.tableWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.space_booking_class.table_click_action)
```

In another python file , there is a class: `BookingSpaceClass`.
In this class I will get some data from database , and put these data into the table widget in the Main window :

```
class BookingSpaceClass:

    def __init__(self, theTable, database):
        self.theTable = theTable
        self.database = database

    def table_click_action(self):
        indexes = self.theTable.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
        data_id = self.theTable.item(indexes[0].row(), 23).text()
        return_data = self.database.read_data_with_id("spacebooking", data_id)
        print(return_data)
```

How can I transfer the data which get from table_click_action to Main window's widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your example why the `BookingSpaceClass` needs to exist at all.  It's just storing references to the exact same gui widgets that the main class does.  The `table_click_action` method could just as easily be on the main class.  You should probably connect the `itemClicked` signal to a slot on the main class and move everything from `BookingSpaceClass` into the main class, or at least call the `BookingSpaceClass` helper methods from the main class instead of using signals.

```
self.tableWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.on_itemClicked)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def on_itemClicked(self)
    return_data = self.space_booking_class.table_click_action()
```